# How can we get the table count with specific date when rows adding day to day?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5

Hi all please help me to get the result on date wise selection

For example I have table and rows on 14-08-2022

```
id name
1   A
2   B
3   C
```

and  rows on 15-08-2022

```
id name
4   D
5   E
```

and  rows on 16-08-2022

```
id name
6   F
7   G
```

If I select date  14-08-2022 i should get result

```
id name
1   A
2   B
3   C
```

If I select date 14-08-2022 to 15-08-2022 I should get result

```
id name
1   A
2   B
3   C
4   D
5   E
```

If I select date 15-08-2022 to 16-08-2022 I should get result

```
id name
4   D
5   E
6   F
7   G
```

Comment: do you have a date or timestamp column in you table?

Comment: No I don't have

Comment: Its a dead end ., Look into : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73375663/is-there-a-way-to-retrieve-records-from-the-past-7-days-without-them-having-a-d