# is there a way to retrieve records from the past 7 days, without them having a date column?

Tags: sql, postgresql

i have this table where i have to retrieve the record from the last 7 days but the table does not have a datetime or date column. its just basic information. im using postgresql btw(not sure if that matthers tho).

Comment: Do you have any way of knowing which records are from the last 7 days?

Comment: nope i wish i did, its not my db.... i never did something like this without a date col.. therefor im stuck right now...

Comment: Do you have daily backups? Query logging turned on? a timestamp field?

Comment: If there is no column that stores this information, there is no way to filter by it.

Comment: A Postgres record does not contain any timestamp meta data, so with no user created timestamp field this is not possible.

Comment: At one time, Postgres had a "time travel" feature that let you see your data at any point in the past, but it's almost certain you're not using that version